# Evaluating a definite integral

Tags: calculus

$$\int_0^1 x\arcsin\left(\sin\left(\pi x\right)\right) dx$$

My work is to sub $\arcsin(\pi x)=y$ but I got a result equal to $\frac{1}{3}\pi$ but when I used Wolfram Alpha to check my answer it answered with 0.39.

Comment: Try to evaluate by parts.

Comment: Please show your work in more detail. What were your next steps?

Comment: HINT:  Enforce the substitution $x\to 1-x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $x$ is between $0$ and $1/2$, $\arcsin(\sin(\pi x))=\pi x$.
But when $x$ is between $1/2$ and $1$, $\sin(\pi x)=\sin(\pi(1-x))$
and $\arcsin(\sin(\pi x))=\pi(1-x)$. Your integral equals
$$\int_0^{1/2}\pi x^2\,dx+\int_{1/2}^1\pi x(1-x)\,dx$$
etc.

Comment: May you explain why it equals to that value when 1/2<x<1

Comment: $\arcsin$ has to be between $\pm\pi/2$.

Comment: Is that to guarante sin is one-to - one so it has an inverse?